# Elastic Search NEST client raw + custom query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST client for querying ES, but now I have a specific situation - I'm trying to proxy query to ES, but with specific query applied by default:

```
public IEnumerable<TDocument> Search<TDocument>(string indexName, string query, string sort, int page, int pageSize) where TDocument : class
{
    var search = new SearchRequest(indexName)
    {
        From = page,
        Size = pageSize,
        Query = new RawQuery(query),
    };


    var response = this.client.Search<TDocument>(search);

    return response.Documents;
}
```

Code above is just proxying query to ES, but what if I need to apply specific filter that should be always applied along with passed query?

So for example I'd want `Active` field to be `true` by default. How can I merge this raw query with some specific and always applied filter (without merging strings to formulate merged ES API call if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `query` is well formed JSON that corresponds to the query DSL, you could deserialize it into an instance of `QueryContainer` and combine it with other queries. For example

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

string query = @"{
  ""multi_match"": {
    ""query"": ""hello world"",
    ""fields"": [
      ""description^2.2"",
      ""myOtherField^0.3""
    ]
  }
}";

QueryContainer queryContainer = null;

using (var stream = client.ConnectionSettings.MemoryStreamFactory.Create(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(query)))
{
    queryContainer = client.RequestResponseSerializer.Deserialize<QueryContainer>(stream);
}

queryContainer = queryContainer && +new TermQuery
{
    Field = "another_field",
    Value = "term"
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<TDocument>(s => s.Query(q => queryContainer));
```

which will translate to the following query (assuming default index is `_all`)

```
POST http://localhost:9200/_all/_search?pretty=true&typed_keys=true 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{
        "term": {
          "another_field": {
            "value": "term"
          }
        }
      }],
      "must": [{
        "multi_match": {
          "fields": ["description^2.2", "myOtherField^0.3"],
          "query": "hello world"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```